# SQL many2many query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, many-to-many

I have 3 tables.

**PersonT:**
id
name

**LotT:**
id
price

**PersonLotT:**
person_id
lot_id

I want to know information like this:
Michael (sum of all him lots, for example 300+400+500=1200)
Alex 900
James 500

I tried to make different queries, but all was wrong.

Comment: People tend to take questions more seriously when posters show what they have already tried.

Comment: What query did you try, and what was wrong with it?

Comment: What queries have you tried? If you provide some samples of what you have done, we can help you understand it a little better by focusing on what you have missed.

Comment: SELECT p.name, sum(l.price)
FROM PersonT as p, LotT as l, PersonLotT as pl
where p.id = pl.person_id and l.id = pl.lot_id
group by p.name I tried this, but i'm really newbie in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    select name, sum(price)
from PersonLotT PL join LotT L on PL.lot_id = L.id
join PersonT P on PL.person_id = P.id
group by name;
```

A sql fiddle is setup for exploring [SQL Fidde](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/944b4/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. It's right

Comment: I'm glad that sql worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

this Query is Helpful in your Scenarios

> select SUM(LotT.price) as TotalPrice, PersonT.Name  from PersonLot
>   join PersonT on PersonLot.personID=PersonT.personid  inner join LotT
>   on PersonLot.Lotid=LotT.id group by PersonT.Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.id, p.name, sum(t.price) as price
from PersonLotT pl
inner join PersonT p on pl.person_id = p.id
inner join LotT l on pl.lot_id = l.id
group by p.id, p.name;
```